# Creating an effect where a div floats on the front of the page (like a conventional application)

Tags: javascript, css, web

The best example site I can give about this effect which I'm struggling to articulate is Facebook. When you click a photo, you get a div that floats on the top of everything enlargening the photo and giving extra info. It's kind of similar to something you'd find in a conventional app - like a sub view kind of thing.

http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v282/Ace_of_Spades01/fb_zps2047caf8.png

Is there a framework or other pre-built solution out there or will I have to roll my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shadowbox let's you do this. It can display HTML and is easy to implement.

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/usage.html

Comment: The API on this does look more concise, so I'll accept this one over the other. Cheers for the recommendation & also that interesting code sample.

Answer (score 2):

The feature you describe is known as a lightbox.

If you use jQuery, you can use something like fancybox - http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

If not, there are many alternatives if you Google 'lightbox'.